# Shopify liquid How to hide out of stock products until click on element at collection page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How I can make an element that will hide the "out of stock items" that will be under the stock items and if someone clicks the button, it will open them?

I added a photo for example:
[image: Here]

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through products available & out of stock in a collection.
Here is sample liquid code:

```
<div id="div1">
// Display all in stock products 
{% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if product.available %}
          {% include 'product-grid-item' %}          
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="div2">
// Display all out of stock products
{% for product in collection.products %}
        {% unless product.available %}
            {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
        {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can use simple js to give expand collapse effect to div2 on click of button.

Note: You can further optimize this code by using single iteration  and storing two div in two variables.